# Open and close Hibernate session

Tags: java, hibernate

This is how I get a Hibernate Session and create query.

```
HSession.getSession().createQuery("query here").executeUpdate();
```

AND

```
Critaria cr=HSession.getSession().createCritaria(..).. ;
```

HSession is where my Session factory is located and `getSession()` method returns  a new session

```
(getSessionFactory().openSession();)
```

I want to know whether

- After calling `cr.list();` Is the session is still alive?
- If alive, getting this criteria or executing a query way is not good? and
- Creating a Session as

  Session s=HSession.getSession();
  s.createCriteria...

  Is the way to use the session and close it using `s.close();` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the session will be alive until you close it.  You can perform multiple operations against a session, but only `close()` will close it.

In your case, it looks like the sessions are controlled by whatever `HSession` is. You'll need to look at that to see if any transactions are performed, how the sessions are managed, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I read about this today ... it said "A Session is opened when getCurrentSession() is called for the first time and closed when the transaction ends."
So according to this: If you have a transaction wrapped around it (and you should have i guess) and call transaction.commit() ... the session is closed.
In your case it should still be open.

Please correct me if I'm wrong with this ... ! :)